# How are child nameservers resolved?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

When specifying DNS information for a domain (e.g. in the registrar control panel) one can use nameservers which are subdomains of the domain. For example, if I have a domain example.com, I can set nameservers "ns1.example.com 1.1.1.1" and "ns2.example.com 1.1.1.2" (IP-addresses are mandatory). What is the process of resolving the name ns1.example.com?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/482913/is-dig-trace-always-accurate

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records):

> Name servers in delegations are identified by name, rather than by IP
>   address. This means that a resolving name server must issue another
>   DNS request to find out the IP address of the server to which it has
>   been referred. If the name given in the delegation is a subdomain of
>   the domain for which the delegation is being provided, there is a
>   circular dependency. In this case the name server providing the
>   delegation must also provide one or more IP addresses for the
>   authoritative name server mentioned in the delegation. This
>   information is called glue. The delegating name server provides this
>   glue in the form of records in the additional section of the DNS
>   response, and provides the delegation in the answer section of the
>   response.

Answer (score 1):

In the zone file for example.com you must have a glue record such as:

```
ns1.example.com 604800 IN A 1.1.1.1
ns2.example.com 604800 IN A 1.1.1.2
```