# How is the IP of a nameserver located in it's own domain resolved?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver

I understand basics of how DNS works. My ISP finds out recursively, that my domain xyz.com is assigned with two nameservers:

ns1.xyzprivatens.com
ns2.xyzprivatens.com

Then it asks one of those two for the xyz.com IP and communicates with server using this IP.

Now is the interesting question. How IPs for the nameservers themselves are resolved?

Comment: I concur, as the possible dup question needs prior knowledge.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/482913/is-dig-trace-always-accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by means of the so-called Glue Records. More information [here on SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record) or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records).

Comment: We normally close these as duplicates rather than answering them

Comment: I really pondered flagging as dupe, but taking the Q&A format into account, I decided to answer instead - i felt the question was more along the lines of *what's needed* rather than *what's that thing that i know is needed*.